# Nested loop on a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

see the code below:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
m=[0,0]
q=[]
for n in a:
    m[0]=n
    for n in a:
        m[1]=n
        q.append(m)
print(q)
```

the desired output should be:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4]]
```

but instead the output is:

```
[[4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4]]
```

any thoughts why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: You are appending the same list each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the same list to `q` each time, so the changes will effect every sublist in `q`.  However, there is a much easier way to do this using a list comprehension:

```
q = [[i, j] for i in a for j in a]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4]]
```

Or using **`itertools`**

```
q = list(itertools.product(a, repeat=2))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In python lists are stored as references in variables, so altering `m` in each iteration affects all `m` references you appended to the `q` list.

Instead, make a copy of `m` with `m[:]` before you append:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
m=[0,0]
q=[]
for n in a:
    m[0]=n
    for n in a:
        m[1]=n
        q.append(m[:])
print(q)
```

This outputs:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4]]
```